# syntax error, unexpected 'while' (t_while) please help :)

Tags: plugins, php

```
function wccg_get_random_coupon() {

    // Generate unique coupon code
    $random_coupon = '';
    $length        = 6;
    $charset       = '0123456789';
    $count         = strlen( $charset )

    while ( $length-- ) {
        for ($random_coupon = 0; $random_coupon <= $count; $random_coupon++) {
        
    $random_coupon = implode( '-', str_split( strtoupper( $random_coupon ), 6 ) );

    // Ensure coupon code is correctly formatted with WC Core filter
    $coupon_code = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_coupon_code', $random_coupon );

    // Additional filter that only executes for this plugin, not for other WC Core coupons
    $random_code = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_coupon_generator_random_coupon_code', $coupon_code );

    return $random_code;
    } }
}
```

I have no clue why this won't work, if anyone could help that'd be great.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `;` on this line:

```
$count         = strlen( $charset )
```

Should be:

```
$count         = strlen( $charset );
```

Comment: Thnx! that was exactly it! code doesnt fully work. but doesnt give errors now haha

Comment: @EasyEden if this is the answer too your question can you mark it as the accepted answer? Use the tick under the voting arrows, both you and Jacob will get reputation points, and the site will acknowledge this question is solved. Otherwise it'll keep suggesting it to people hoping they'll come give you an answer